# Convert 24 hours to 12 hours in dart

Tags: dart, time

I want method to convert string 24 hours time format to 12 format
For example the method takes string 16:30
Then return string 4:30 pm
The intl package do not work because the package needs the data and time but I'm reading the time from Jason file without date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an option

```
    String convertTo12(String hhMM) {
      final arr = hhMM.split(':');
      final h = int.tryParse(arr[0]);
      return '${h > 12 ? h % 12 : h}:${arr[1]}';
    }
```

```
  final str = '16:30';
  print(convertTo12(str)); // 4:30
```

Comment: yes it works I just need to make test for h to specify whatever to add PM or AM